# Puppet: Restart service on package update

Tags: puppet

So you manage a package that should be always at its latest version:

```
package { "openssl":
  ensure => 'latest',
}
```

Is it possible to restart a service if the package version changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the following works perfectly:

```
service { apache2:
  ensure          => running,
  enable          => true,
  subscribe       => Package['openssl'],
  restart         => "/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest && /etc/init.d/apache2 reload",
}
```

Comment: Was just typing this up. you can also use `notify => Service['apache2']` if you want to do it the opposite way.

Comment: Correct, but maybe use `restart => 'service apache2 graceful'` ?  You'll probably find the `configtest` is built in.  If you are going to use `apachectl` directly, `apachectl graceful` does the `configtest` and is probably what your `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` is doing anyway.

Comment: Good point ...  !